# Macbook Pro Mid-2015 Backlight Burning Bright

Tags: macbook-pro, backlight

When I arrived at home today, my Macbook Pro was frozen. When I rebooted, the backlight looks like this:

[image]

After logging in, I can still see the backlight edges, as if it's turned too brightly, or "burned out".

The model is a MJLQ2. External monitor outputs work fine. I turned off Flux and Night Shift, but the problem persists. Calibrating white point did not fix it either.

Is this reparable and is it covered under warranty?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it repairable?

Yes.  The backlight or the entire screen assembly can (should) be replaced.  This is something you can do yourself with a [replacement LCD](http://radnex.us/mbp-2015-retina-display-15) and the instructions from [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Display+Assembly+Replacement/55925).  It's basically removing the back panel, disconnect the display and WiFi cables, then detaching the assembly brackets/hinges.

> is it covered under warranty?

When did you purchase it?  Within 1 year (US) it will be covered.   Is you MacBook Pro still covered under AppleCare (extended warranty)?  If not, it's likely this will be an out-of-pocket expense.

[Check your Apple service coverage](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) to verify.